# Regularization for approximation in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, approximation

In the case of approximation tasks using neural networks, should we standardize the data, as in the classification ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "regularize the data"? Do you mean standardize the data *or* regularize the parameters in the loss-function?

Comment: standardize the data, sorry for misleading

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: guess you mean scaling data, so setting mean zero and covariance to unit. And yes you should!

Comment: Ok, but should we also standardize the output variable ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let' think of an example: So we have data
$\boldsymbol{x}_{1} = \left[\begin{array}  -1,1  \end{array} \right]^{T} + \boldsymbol{b}  $
and $\boldsymbol{x}_{2} = \left[\begin{array}  11 ,1  \end{array} \right]^{T} + \boldsymbol{b}  $
with $\lVert b \rVert|  \gg 1 $. And $y_{1} = 0$, $y_{2}=2$.

The loss is assumed to be MSE: $L(n) =  \lVert y_{n} - \boldsymbol{w}_{1}\boldsymbol{x}_{n} \rVert ^{2} $.
Now let's calculate the derivatives:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}_{1}} L =\left[ \begin{array}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial w_{12}}   L , \frac{\partial}{\partial w_{12}}  L\end{array} \right]^{T}=-2\boldsymbol{x}_{n}(y_{n}-\boldsymbol{w}_{1}\boldsymbol{x}_{n})$.

Calculating this for $n=1$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}_{1}} L \approx -2\left[ \begin{array}
bb ,b  \end{array} \right]^{T} (y_{1}-\boldsymbol{w}_{1}\boldsymbol{x}_{1})$.

So we see that the offset $\boldsymbol{b}$ is the dominant part.

Comment: Actually, can somebody tell me what's wrong with the TeX in here?